# Having the same class work as a Property Bag and a series of Properties

Tags: c#, dictionary, properties

My C# class works as a holder for a bunch of values, which now are stored as properties. In a move to increase extensibility I'm going to add a Dictionary to it, so that people can store whatever properties they want in there, without having to change the class code. However I would like to keep backwards compatibility, by allowing the old properties to still be accessed either through the bag accessor or the  the original getter setter. I.e. I want the following two pieces of codes to have the same effect.

```
properties.Config1 = value
properties["Config1"] = value
```

Does anyone have any tips on best practices for such a change? One complication is that some existing getter setter have validation/logic in them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to preserve backwards compatibility, you can't expose the Dictionary directly. Instead, you can implement an [indexer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x16t2tx.aspx) on your class and put some checks within it to ensure that the appropriate logic is run when one of the existing properties is accessed using that syntax.

If you do it with an indexer, you have the option of putting the existing properties into the Dictionary, or just leaving them as is and calling their existing getters and setters from the indexer's getter/setter when the appropriate string is passed as a key.

The indexer might look something like this:

```
public object this[string key] {
    get {
        if (key == "Config1") return this.Config1;
        else return propBag[key];
    }
    set {
        if (key == "Config1") this.Config1 = value;
        else propBag[key] = value;
    }
}
```

Of course, you might want to add checks to ensure the key exists in the `else` block, but this should get you started.

---

One more thing to consider: changing this class to add property bag behavior, whether implemented as a public dictionary or indexer, will cause the class's interface to change. So, you won't have to *rewrite* existing code, but you will have to *recompile* it once you change the class.

Comment: Good answer. What do you see of so egregious with the decision of turning the object into a property bag?

Comment: I'm not saying it's a bad decision, it just pops up a red flag for me when I think about it. Obviously, you know your system and I don't, so it's up to you to decide if it's an issue or not. If it works for you, by all means, go with it. I added that because I don't want somebody to find this question a year from now and go running off to turn all their objects into a poor man's expando object without thinking about the consequences.

Comment: Think about it differently: maybe it should have been a proper property bag to begin with. (The class serves as a container for propeties)

Comment: True enough. In that case, it sounds like a pretty good fit. I'll update the answer to remove that since it's not very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Use `ExpandoObject` which is in fact a dictionary of string/object with a syntactic sugar:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject.aspx

Have `properties` as an `ExpandoObject`. Here is the sample from MSDN:

```
dynamic employee = new ExpandoObject();
employee.Name = "John Smith";
employee.Age = 33;

foreach (var property in (IDictionary<String, Object>)employee)
{
    Console.WriteLine(property.Key + ": " + property.Value);
}
// This code example produces the following output:
// Name: John Smith
// Age: 33
```

Comment: This is a interesting idea  if you are using C# 4.0 ... but it does have a certain amount of overhead...

Comment: ExpandObject looks great... if only this was a new class. Remember that I'm retrofitting old code, so I cannot change the class hierarchy.

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't you just replace your references to the internal fields '_config1' to point to the dictionary store instead? You'd need to implement some logic to check if the dictionary key exists etc. but it shouldn't be that monumental of a change.

Comment: What about getter setters with additional logic? If people access the dictionary directly they will bypass any extra code on gets sets.

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking to implement something similar to this myself, and both backwards and forwards compatibility are issues.

I'm looking to use reflection within my property bag to check if the base class implements that property explicitly, and if it does, have the Property Bag refer to the base implementation instead.

For example, if my class implements:

```
string MyClass.Name
```

Then internally the property bag will use reflection to forward requests of `MyClass.Properties["Name"]` to `MyClass.Name`

This can cause a problem.  If users of my class have, for example, set up an ad-hoc property `list(of string) MyClass.Properties["Address"]`, and then I implement a default property `string Myclass.Address` - this will obviously cause the users code to break.

This isn't an issue for the environment I'm developing in though.

Answer (score 0):

Below is a pretty good article regarding some aspects of code design for anyone who wants to make a "PropertyBag"-type class, and who doesn't want the overhead of `System.Dynamic`

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12282/Implementing-a-PropertyBag-in-C